# Shader Noise and CPU Noise

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, noise

I've come across an issue, where I am using a custom shader to offset the vertices of a (flat) mesh using noise. this is fine, and works well:

[image]

I also want to generate a collision mesh for this - which requires the use of CPU-based noise. I am usin "noiseSimplex.cginc" that can be found online, but want to implement a c# version that gives the same result. Is there a suggested way of approaching this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to calculate the mesh on the CPU anyways, there is no further advantage in having it calculated on the GPU.
Do your mesh transformation on the CPU and use that mesh for both the rendering and the collision.

Edit:

Assuming a case where you mostly need the mesh for rendering only, but sometimes you want to have it on the CPU for processing, you might consider having it generated on the GPU with the possibility to download it as required.

I'm not up to date on shader technology, but last time I looked (DirectX 10 times), you might have generated the mesh purely using a geometry shader into a buffer on the GPU. Then you can use that buffer to feed into your rendering as well as download it to the CPU if required.

It's quite possible that this is no longer the way to do it today, but it should work.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, that is true, except I might not want EVERY mesh to also be processed by the CPU. E.g. terrain systems might want to show you the terrain, but collision mesh is not required, due to LOD, or another factor. If we are talking about terrain chunks for example, a chunk might be visible - so the shader must be displacing the mesh, but no collision is needed - this saves a huge amount of processing by the CPU, and the mesh for rendering can be shared across every chunk.